# Help with smoothing surface of mesh

Tags: geometry

[image]

How do I rid my mesh of its uneven surface. I tried subdividing the mesh, but I'm wondering why the rectangular geometry still persists after so much smoothing.

Comment: Did you use the modifier to subdivide it?

Comment: I did use the modifier.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get rid of the rectangles on the surface of the mesh.

Comment: Did you give your model anything else appart from subdivision surface?

Comment: sub surf modifier

Comment: It would be easier to know what the issue is if you posted a wireframe version of your mesh without the subdivision modifier.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: I will as soon as I can get to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Give your model Smooth Shading, go to (Tool Shelf) and under Shading section choose **Smooth**